# django migrations making no changes to my admin site after altering my model.py

Tags: python, django

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='awesome')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)
```

i add this field

```
title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='awesome')
```

after having my app installed in my settings.py and makingmigrations i still have no changes in my site admin
i tried deleting the db.sqlite3 and deleting my initial migrations but not change still.

```
blog\migrations\0002_alter_post_title_tag.py
    - Alter field title_tag on post
```

Comment: Please add some more details about your issue, better add any error trace if available

Comment: there are no errors, when i visit my django admin site the changes i made to my model.py is not altered in the site

Comment: Please share the site admin. The migrations have *nothing* to do with the site admin.

Comment: Did you add `Post` model in admin.py?

Comment: did you register your model in admin.py